# Matplotlib offsetImage reduces resolution

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to insert several png images into a plot as described [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_annotation_box.html),
using the likes of

```
img_1 = read_png('path_to_file.png')
imbox_1 = OffsetImage(img_1, zoom=scale_factor)
```

where scale_factor is between 0 and 1.

This works as intended, but the resolution of the inserted images is terrible. How do I prevent this downscaling?

Comment: This is a very reduced code-example. I suspect, in your case everything boils down to the original figure size / dpi? How did you define this?

Comment: I guess the usual applies here as well. When reporting about undesired behaviour make that undesired behaviour reproducible for others. See [mcve]. As I don't think the image in the example you link to looks terrible, it is not quite clear what you are expecting. I would also think that `zoom=1` (original size) should give the nicest picture.

Answer (score 0):

If it's anything like my problem it's because the dpi of the output savefig was too low

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).